# How to ensure float value is not out of bound?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
float numb = 0.00f;
if (numb < FLT_MIN || numb > FLT_MAX)
    printf("NOT Valid");
else
    printf("Valid");
```

In this case, why `0.00f` not valid?

Comment: Did you mean `numb < -FLT_MAX`? The `FLT_MIN` does not work the same way as `INT_MIN`. And the only way a `float` can exceed `FLT_MAX` is if it is infinite.

Comment: @WeatherVane how would you write the if statement then?

Comment: Please state what you are trying to achieve. Your code might make sense if you are wanting to convert a *`double`* value to `float`. Say `double d = DBL_MAX; if(d >= FLT_MIN && d <= FLT_MAX) numb = (float)d`. But as mentioned, a `float` value can only be larger than `FLT_MAX` if it is infinite.

Comment: I am trying to ensure the value is between FLT_MIN and FLT_MAX

Comment: It ***cannot*** be outside that range unless it is ***infinite***. The limits are about the storage capacity of the type.

Comment: A negative value will also not be between FLT_MIN and FLT_MAX. Both these constants are positive.

Comment: What you are doing is like having a 1 litre jug and asking if there is more than 1 litre of water in it.

Answer (score 2):

`FLT_MIN` is like the *smallest* positive value a (normalized) `float` may have. It's slightly above 0, on today's platforms:

```
FLT_MIN = 1/2^126 = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001175494350822
```

because `0` is smaller then `FLT_MIN`, `numb < FLT_MIN` is true.

To check if a `float` is not NAN nor infinity, I would go with [isfinite()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isfinite):

```
if (isfinite(numb))
```

> I am trying to ensure the value is between FLT_MIN and FLT_MAX

Then of your code in the first the edit was correct. To check a variable is in range, I usually write like `min < var && var < max` so the smaller is on the left side of `<` - it's easier to read for my head.

```
if (FLT_MIN < numb && numb < FLT_MAX)
```

`0` is smaller then `FLT_MIN`, so it is not within that range. Fun fact: subnormal numbers like `FLT_MIN / 2` are also not within that range.

Answer (score 0):

The only way it could be "out of bounds" is if it is infinite, which is a special value.

FLT_MIN does not work the same way as INT_MIN. So your if statement "should" look like this:

```
if (numb < -FLT_MIN || numb > FLT_MAX)
```

But this really doesn't make any sense. You're basically testing if it has a value it cannot have. Which it of course will not.

Use the function `isfinite()` for this.